# Search a term in Gmail and Ignore Attachments

Tags: gmail

Is it possible search Gmail for a term and ignore occurrences of the search term in attachments?

Comment: I am aware of the has:attachment operator but that is not helpful here even in an exclusion, !has:attachment, because I want to find occurrences of the term in subject or the body of the message whether or not the message has attachments. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: you can try to add a label to all of your emails with attachments and when you search again you just exclude such label, that could work.